# Android application not showing up in app menu

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I have made an application that uses the Google Maps and Google location services API's. I can run the app through Android Studio but the app icon does not appear in my app menu. Here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<permission
    android:name="edu.vesit.deliveryapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="edu.vesit.deliveryapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXX" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="Register">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="DeliveryApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Comment DEFAULT category from intent filter & check.

Comment: Does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<permission
    android:name="edu.vesit.deliveryapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="edu.vesit.deliveryapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXX" />

    <activity
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="Register">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="DeliveryApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

Add icon in your main launcher activity as well.